# Key Value Storage for django ? editable in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings, key-value-store

I need some good way to provide admin users of my django 1.5 app, manage some various app parameters, these parameters or settings are different from the app core settings, ... can anyone point some directions for this ??

thanks everyone

Comment: Can you clarify your question?? Do you need to set the parameters in your settings.py ?

Comment: No, for instance I want the admin user to be able to set app specific parameters like default_product_price = $10 using django-admin, the parameter doesnt need to be in settings file, .. just somewhere (database probably) where I can retrieve it easily

Answer (score 1):

You can create an app and use a Model to handle all the possible parameters that you need to use. Then register your admin for this app, and you will be able to change an use this values.

I always have a utils app, that I can put some code that can be shared within the project and along all the projects that I work, so I can give you a suggestion to put this in your utils app:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Parameters(models.Model):

    default_product_price = models.IntegerField(default=10) # you can change this in admin
    ...
```

Then, register your classes in admin.py